# Failed opening required 'application/models/proxies/__CG__modelsCountry.php'

Tags: php, doctrine, pear, proxyfactory

I have entities `Country` and `City` with relationship `OneToMany` from `Country` and `ManyToOne` from `City` , which are as follows :

**`Country.php`**

```
<?php
namespace models;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use Gedmo\Mapping\Annotation as Gedmo,
    Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection;
/**
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="models\repository\CountryRepository")
 * @ORM\Table(name="Country")
 *
 */
class Country{
    /**
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255, nullable=false)
     */
    private $name;

    /**
     * @var datetime $created
     *
     * @Gedmo\Timestampable(on="create")
     * @ORM\Column(type="datetime")
     */
    private $created;

    /**
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="models\City",mappedBy="country")
     */
    private $cities;

    //getters and setters 
}
```

**`City.php`**

```
class City{
    /**
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue
     */
    private $id;

   /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="models\Country")
     */

    private $country;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255, nullable=false)
     */
    private $name;

    //getters and setters
}
```

When I try to fetch a city with cityId (say 1),

```
$city_ = $this->doctrine->em->find('models\City', 1);
```

the error I get is

```
Fatal error: require(): Failed opening required 'application/models/proxies/__CG__modelsCountry.php' (include_path='.:/usr/share/php:/usr/share/pear') in /var/www/MyCIApp/application/third_party/Doctrine/ORM/Proxy/ProxyFactory.php on line 93
```

The line no 93 can viewed at [doctrine2 (github)](https://github.com/iPrayag/doctrine2/blob/master/lib/Doctrine/ORM/Proxy/ProxyFactory.php#L92)


### NOTE:

1 - my `/etc/php5/apache2/php.ini` is

```
;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;
; Paths and Directories ;
;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;

; UNIX: "/path1:/path2"
;include_path = ".:/usr/share/php"
;
; Windows: "\path1;\path2"
;include_path = ".;c:\php\includes"
;
; PHP's default setting for include_path is ".;/path/to/php/pear"
; http://php.net/include-path
;include_path=".:/usr/share/php/pear"
; The root of the PHP pages, used only if nonempty.
; if PHP was not compiled with FORCE_REDIRECT, you SHOULD set doc_root
; if you are running php as a CGI under any web server (other than IIS)
; see documentation for security issues.  The alternate is to use the
; cgi.force_redirect configuration below
; http://php.net/doc-root
```

2 - When I fetch entity having no relationship with any other entity, for eg

```
class Sector{
    /**
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255, nullable=false)
     */
    private $description;
}
```

it works well

```
$sector = $this->doctrine->em->find('models\Sector', 1);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`sudo mkdir application/models/proxies` works perfectly. `Doctrine` was not creating `proxies` folder for me.

Answer (score 1):

I got this problem because I was trying to load fixtures before running:

```
./vendor/bin/doctrine-module orm:schema-tool:create
```

When I ran this, my proxy classes were generated and the error went away.

The doctrine command 'generate-proxies' may well have also fixed this issue:

```
./vendor/bin/doctrine-module orm:generate-proxies
```